# Best way to insert multiple rows into SQL Server 2008 database from .NET 4.0 app

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, insert, bulk

I have a scenario where I get back a list of items and I need to insert each item into a database, with one item > one row mapping.

Initially, I thought about using a stored procedure that would insert a single item, and looping over a list, calling the stored procedure for each element. But I wonder if there are more elegant/optimal methods available. Especially leveraging SQL Server 2008 / .NET 4.0.

Entity Framework could also come into play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLBulkCopy is quick and easy, you can set up a batch size and map all of your columns

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways you can do bulk inserts.

1. Use a SqlDataAdapter, set the InsertCommand on it, and call .Update with e.g. a DataTable ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update.aspx)). This can batch up the inserts into batch sizes of your choosing.
2. Use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class (better performance possible with this).
3. Create a sproc that takes a TABLE valued parameter - then pass a table of data in for that sproc to insert in one go ([MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx))

I've previously blogged about the performance of option 1 vs. option 2 [here](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sqlbulkcopy-bulk-load-to-sql-server.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework you could do:

```
yourContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
yourContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Do `SaveChanges()` in packages of 100 inserts... try with 1000 and see the changes.

Since during all this inserts, the context is the same, you can rebuild your context object every 1000 inserts.

```
 var yourContext = new YourContext();
```

Doing this improvements in an importing data process of mine, took it from 7 minutes to 6 seconds.

The actual numbers... could not be 100's o 1000's in your case... try it and tweek it.